# How to port BlitzBasic 3D to BlitzMax IDE

Tags: porting, blitz3d, blitzmax

Can someone help me on porting a game written in BlitzBasic to BlitzMax IDE. I tried running the .bb file into MaxIDE but it says "process failure with file.bb". Also where can i find more information regarding this?

Answer (score 1):

You must rename the `.bb` files to `.bmx`. Though a superset, BlitzBasic is a completely different language than BlitzMax.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the [BlitzMax IDE Community Edition](https://www.blitzcoder.org/forum/topic.php?id=48) project which has the feature to import `.bb` files then convert them to `.bmx` files.

In regard to the 3D commands part and as Spark Fountain as mentioned, it is not supported by default, but you can use [MiniB3D](https://github.com/si-design/minib3d) or [OpenB3DMax](https://github.com/markcwm/openb3dmax.mod).

http://blitzmax-ide.sourceforge.net/

[BlitzMax IDE Community Edition](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4XCJF.png)

Answer (score 0):

**BlitzMax** introduces several new features such as classes, real object orientation, inheritance and many more. Anyways, most of the **BlitzBasic** syntax elements remain or can at least be re-used.

To port your BlitzBasic programs to BlitzMax, I suggest you [learn and understand the basic language elements](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/BlitzMax/Language). You can also use the following guide as a starting point.

- comments start with `'` or `REM` instead of `;`
- arrays are defined with `Local array[10]` instead of `Dim array(10)`
- 3D commands are not supported but you could use i. e. [MiniB3D](https://github.com/si-design/minib3d)